# Tracking user activity on window opened by window.open() method

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, ftp, window.open

I want to open a ftp browser at client site so that he can upload files in ftp.
I am using `window.open()` method to open the ftp in a child window.

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open("ftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server,
                                         _blank', toolbar=yes, location=yes, status=yes,
                                         scrollbars=auto, copyhistory=no, 
                                         menubar=yes, width= 500px, height=500px,
                                         left=300px), top=100px, resizable=yes' );
```

The ftp looks like this:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6WYg.jpg

now i want to track the user activity like directories he visited,and send the path to the jsp page how to do that...??

Comment: Do that on the ftp server. It's not possible on do to on your web server.

Comment: So, how can we browse the ftp server from client end like browsing local computer?

Comment: You can't. Tracking the content of a window which shows an external site is not possible for security reasons (same origin policy). All you could do is to provide your own interface to the ftp server, i.e. do some code at the web server side which connects to the ftp server etc - kind of proxy with a nice interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, browser windows with different domains can't see each other ([same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). On top of that, the `ftp` protocol doesn't support any kind of JavaScript which would allow you to track what the user does.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Analyze the log files of the FTP server to see what the user did.
2. Instead of redirecting to `ftp://` directly, write a JSP which gives access to the files on the FTP server. That way, you can track anything that the user does.

For solution #2, the files need to be on the web server or you need to use a Java library which can talk to an FTP server.

Note: The FTP client in the browser is probably implemented using HTML and JavaScript but all this code is hidden somewhere in the browser. So even though the display is HTML and JavaScript, you can't access it.

Comment: so how can i implement a customerized interface so that client can only upload their files diectly to ftp server?

Comment: You can use HTTP upload instead.

Comment: should i write the code for browsing the ftp directories in jsp page?

Comment: I wrote: "write a JSP which gives access to the files on the FTP server."